# removing rows from dataframe based on condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Code": ['9958S135K108MF-1','9958S135-1','9958S105-1','9958S105K84MF-1',], "ID": ['FO995877000581098', 'FO995877000581098','FO995877000581098','FO995877000581098',], "NUM": ['9958S135','9958S135','9958S105','9958S105']})
```

I need the following output:

```
    Code                ID                  NUM
0   9958S135K108MF-1    FO995877000581098   9958S135
3   9958S105K84MF-1     FO995877000581098   9958S105
```

For every `"ID"` there should be a unique `"NUM"`. There will be many duplicate `"ID"`

The trick is upon dropping the row which has a duplicate '"ID"' and "'NUM" I need to remove the row that has the prefix ending in `MF-1`..

I have tried to add a `"Mapping"` column and delete `True` values in that column but it will not always allocate `"True"` to the correct row which `"Code"` contains 'MF-1'.

Here is what I have tried:

```
import pandas as pd

df['Mapping'] = df['NUM'].eq(df['NUM'].shift()) & df['ID'].eq(df['ID'].shift())

    Code                ID                  NUM         Mapping
0   9958S135K108MF-1    FO995877000581098   9958S135    False
1   9958S135-1          FO995877000581098   9958S135    True
2   9958S105-1          FO995877000581098   9958S105    False
3   9958S105K84MF-1     FO995877000581098   9958S105    True
```

Comment: do you want to drop the ones that have `MF-1` in the `Code`? or do you want to keep them? I am confused

Comment: I want to keep the ones that have `MF-1` in the code

Answer (score 0):

I was able to acheive my outcome using the following:

```
df[~df.duplicated(['ID', 'NUM'], keep=False) | df['Code'].astype(str).str.contains('MF-1')]
```